# Handling a steamwriter after a failed network recovery

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter

I'm using a StreamWriter to copy over chunks from one file into another. Both files are in the same remote location but the process runs on my local machine. I'm trying to recover and continue the process in the event the network hiccups. I'm simulating this by stepping through my code and disabling my network connection at specific moments.

The problem is when I bring my network back up, I am unable to do anything with the StreamWriter. Calling `Flush()`,  `Close()` or `Dispose()` throws the IOException "The specified network name is no longer available". My code looks like this:

```
int charsToRead = 100;
while(!inputFileStream.EndOfStream)
{
    char[] block = new char[charsToRead];
    int charsRead = inputFileStream.ReadBlock(block, 0, charsToRead);
    outputFileStream.Write(new string(block, 0, charsRead));
    outputFileStream.Flush();
}
```

What is the best way to continue with the StreamWriter after recovering from a network failure? Thanks.

Update: I'm working with text files.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a Using-block?

Comment: This doesn’t address your question, but I think you should know that `StreamReader/-Writer` does **not** read bytes, it reads *characters*. You have indeed allocated a `char[]`, but you called your variable `bytesRead`, which is wrong. You should only use `StreamReader/-Writer` if the files are *text* files. If you want to copy any kind of data, please use `FileStream` (which you create using `File.Open()`).

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have any choices. Clean up any objects, repair any harm, and either give up or retry.

Comment: @Timwi indeed - and maybe not even then! Since this case is a raw copy, the Stream API is a better choice, you are right.

Comment: @nthpixel using a using-block will clean up the StreamWriter-object when exiting that block. So when an exception occurs, the object is properly disposed. It could be a start to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, what I meant was: You should only use `StreamReader/-Writer` if the purpose of your code is to read (and process) text from a text file.

Comment: @Koen valid point. I failed to mention that I intend to copy content from multiple files into this one output file. I figured the optimized approach is to keep the output stream open as I'm iterating through the input file. Won't using the `using` statement close the stream every time? Then I'll need to re-open it when I process the next input file.

Comment: @nthpixel Yes, exiting the using-block will close the streamwriter

Answer (score 0):

What does the destination file look like after the network connection goes down in the middle of writing to it? This is important to know, as your recovery strategy necessarily depends on that.

I suspect that what is likely to happen is that the destination file is blanked out to 0 bytes. If that happens, unfortunately you cannot resume the copy process because the already-copied data is gone. All you can do now is re-instantiate the streams and restart the copy from scratch. For large files this may mean that it might never finish if there is a transient network failure all the time.

However, if the destination file is successfully written to even in the face of network failure, then you can use `File.Append()` to re-open the file and continue the copy process. You should then use `inputFile.Position = outputFile.Position` so that the reading and writing are in sync again.

If the network connection to the *input* file fails (the one you’re reading from), just re-open it with `File.Open()` and set `inputFile.Position = outputFile.Position` again.

All of the above assumes that you should use a `Stream` to read the data as *bytes*, which seems to me a more appropriate approach than the one you posted, where you read *characters* using a `StreamReader` (which assumes that the input is a *text* file).

Comment: I'm using a StreamReader/Writer to work with text files. I prefer not to use StreamReader as the code is part of a framework and I don't want to go down that rabbit hole. After the network goes down, the dest file remains in tact with the previous text written to it. I currently keep track of the number of characters successfully copied. I then re-open the input file and seek to the last character with `inputFileStream.BaseStream.Seek(charsCopied, SeekOrigin.Begin)`. This works fine. But I'm having trouble reopening the output file. I also tried outputFileStream = null with no success.

Comment: ① You have to close the outputFileStream explicitly (preferably with a `using` statement). ② There is absolutely no way that you can know how many characters have been copied successfully except by examining the destination file. Any particular call to `Write` that throws an exception *could* have been successful or unsuccessful. ③ I don’t buy that “rabbit hole” argument. You’re digging a rabbit hole of your own by using the wrong tool for the task. ④ `.Seek(x, SeekOrigin.Begin)` is exactly the same as `.Position = x`.